# Cannot get mySQL.connector to download/work?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, connector

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to a MySQL database, unfortunately I cannot get it to connect. The error is:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ python HexCodeImporter2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "HexCodeImporter2.py", line 1, in <module>
 import mySQL.connector
ImportError: No module named mySQL.connector
```

The code that is used on the pi to send the data to the server is below:

```
import mySQL.connector
import serial


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
s = [0]
while True:
read_serial = ser.readline()
print read_serial

con =     mySQL.connector.connect(user="*******",password="********",host="sql8.freemysqlhosting.net",port="3306",database="CheckIn_System")


c = conn.cursor()

c.execute("insert into CheckIn_System values(read_serial,20170404132401)")
```

I have tried to download the mySQL.connector but with no luck. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe the preferred way to connect to MySQL database from Python is with MySQLdb

If MySQLdb not installed don’t worry it’s a quick install.

- Windows Users can get it here: [MySQL for Python Installer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/files/latest/download?source=files)
- Linux Users you can get the [Linux Install](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) and install it by hand, or
  use your package manager and look for python-mysql

Any write code in following way

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", # your host, usually localhost
                     user="username", # your username
                     passwd="password", # your password
                     db="database_name") # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor() 

cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")

cur.close()  # close the cursor

db.close ()   # close the connection
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know python, but something that occurs to me is that you're not calling the correct variable name.

`import mySQL.connector`

should possibly be:

`import con`, as "con" is what you've called the variable holding the connection details to mysql.

You should also move away from the old standard mysql to at least mysqli (improved) if not pdo.https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use--net-24059